# Logging a parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, report

I'm using C# and asp.net with SQL Sever 2012 and want to log an environmental signals on a database (like temperature or humidity). I want to retrieve logged information to make reports and create charts. In your opinion what's the best method to do the job?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to this example hope it shall be helpful

http://stevenjohnston.co.uk/2012/12/12/net-gadgeteer-temperature-logger-example/